# RDLC: How to write the correct logical statement to display different address lines?

Tags: rdlc

I need to change the logic in `rdlc` statement to display 2 address lines in address section.

The address section can be generated as one of the following:

```
Company Name
John Smith
Address 1
Address 2
City, State, Zip

Company Name
John Smith
Address 2
City, State, Zip

Company Name
John Smith
Address 1
City, State, Zip
```

I have a logic that displays empty line if Address 2 is empty or does not exists:

```
Company Name
John Smith

Address 1
City, State, Zip
```

This is my statement:

```
  =First(Fields!Address.Value, "Dataset") & VbCrLf & 
  IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!Address2.Value, "Dataset")) or First(Fields!Address2.Value, "Dataset") = "","",
  First(Fields!Addess2.Value, "Dataset")) & VbCrLf & 
  IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!Address3.Value, "Dataset")) or First(Fields!Address3.Value, "Dataset") = "","",
  First(Fields!Address3.Value, "Dataset"))
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the right way to do it?